# CSS3 selector link text node

Tags: html, css-selectors

I have the following Bash pipeline:

```
curl -sL ... 'http://example.com' | css3selector 'table > tbody > tr > th > a'
```

which returns the following HTML output:

```
<a href="xxx">text</a>
```

css3selector is a tool which extracts HTML elements using a CSS3 selector.
I would like to add another CSS3 selector to the expression `table > tbody > tr > th > a` in order to extract only the text node *text*.

Is it possible and if so how?

Regards, Stefano

Comment: Not with a selector. You will have to process the output of css3selector differently, e.g. by using an HTML parser.

Comment: Thanks for your promptly reply @BoltClock, I will process the output of css3selector with `xml2json | jq`; I thought it was possible to apply some function to it, like for example `table > tbody > tr > th > a.text`, however, it is good to know.

Comment: Good to know. I'll post an answer so you can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with a selector, as selectors only match elements.

You will have to process the output of css3selector differently, e.g. by using an HTML parser.